# Error Message: Unable to get value of the property 'replace': object is null or undefined in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have written some jQuery to take the alt description of an image then strip out spaces and replace &'s with "and" and also replace "/" with "-'s". The below works fine in firefox and chrome but ie IE9 I am getting this:
Error Message: Unable to get value of the property 'replace': object is null or undefined

```
$(".cruiseline").bind("click", function () {
    var altTag = $(this).children("img").attr("alt");
    var logosrc = altTag;
    var logosrc = logosrc.replace(/ /g, '').replace(/\//g, '-').replace("&", "and").toLowerCase();
    $("#cloudfive").html("<img src=\"/logos\/" + logosrc + ".jpg\" />");
});
```

I realise that logosrc is seen as undefined, but it shouldn't be. Have I misused the .replace function?

Cheers

Comment: You have two var keywords. Also use on instead of bind

Comment: seams to work? => http://jsfiddle.net/76rDC/3/

Comment: u have declared logosrc twice.

Comment: Based on your answer below, and since you left out the code that was causing the problem, this should be closed as "too localized" for not being helpful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this line above my jQuery removing the inner html

```
$("#cruiselines").html("");
```

Of the parent of the div I was clicking to get the img alt of, in firefox and chrome it was forgiving, but in IE, it was saying the alt is undefined, because the element didnt exist anymore. I am so stupid... thanks for your help

Comment: This line should have been in your OP all along.  Otherwise, you're the only person in the world able to post the correct answer to your question.  I believe the whole thing should be closed as "too localized".